# Removing Blank Line in Unordered List

Tags: php, jquery, html, zend-framework

Unordered List Function
I currently have three variables from a database, $firstline, $secondline, $thirdline, but sometimes one of the variables is empty. When I try to put it in an unordered list, there's a blank line in that field. How do I write a function that checks for a blank variable and then excludes that variable if it is empty. Basically something that goes "while firstline, secondline, thirdline is not blank, then create this unordered list. If firstline is empty, remove it from unordered list etc.."

```
  <ul>
    echo "<li>$this->firstline</li>";
    echo "<li>$this->secondline</li>";
    echo "<li>$this->thirdline</li>";
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$('li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().trim() === '';
}).remove();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AmNXv/1/)

With plain JavaScript:

```
function removeEmpty(tags, parent){
    if (!tags) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        tags = tags.split(/\s+/);
        parent = parent && parent.nodeType === 1 ? parent : document.body;
        var children = [], _tmp;
        for (var i = 0, len = tags.length; i < len; i++) {
            _tmp = parent.getElementsByTagName(tags[i]);
            if (_tmp.length) {
                for (var I = 0, Len = _tmp.length; I < Len; I++){
                    children.push(_tmp[I]);
                }
            }
        }
        if (children.length > -1) {
            var i = children.length - 1,
                cur, txt;
            while (i) {
                cur = children[i];
                txt = (cur.textContent || cur.innerText).replace(/(^\s+)|($\s+)/g,'');
                if (!txt.length) {
                    cur.parentNode.removeChild(cur);
                }
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}

removeEmpty('li em', document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AmNXv/5/)

Which is remarkably long-winded, but most of the length is to allow for allowing multiple tags in one function call, so you can call the function:

- [`removeEmpty('li em', document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]);`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AmNXv/5/) (as in the code-block above).
- [`removeEmpty('li', document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]);`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AmNXv/3/).
- [`removeEmpty('li');`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AmNXv/4/).

With CSS:

```
li:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AmNXv/)

Though this considers even a single white-space `<li> </li>` to be a non-empty element.

Possibly with PHP (it's been quite some time since I last used *any* PHP):

```
echo strlen($this->firstline) > 0 ? "<li>$this->firstline</li>" : '';
echo strlen($this->secondline) > 0 ? "<li>$this->secondline</li>" : '';
echo strlen($this->thirdline) > 0 ? "<li>$this->thirdline</li>" : '';
```

Comment: For the PHP bit you'd use `!empty($this->firstline)` instead of `strlen`

Comment: As noted it's been quite a while since I so much as looked at PHP, but I'm interested: is there a reason to use `!empty()` rather than `strlen() > 0`, or is it just an alternative approach?

Comment: Just an alternative approach; but it's shorter, more readable, and `empty()` is a language construct rather than a function so it may well be faster (by a miniscule amount).

Answer (score 1):

A function can be like this

```
function checkEmpty($val){

if(!$val) return;
if($val) return "<li>".$val."</li>";

}
```

Now you can use this function

```
echo checkEmpty($this->firstline);
echo checkEmpty($this->secondline);
echo checkEmpty($this->thirdline);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `return $val ? '<li>' . $val . '</li>' : '';` be slightly more concise?

Answer (score 0):

as you are displaying your list dynamically in php try something like this

```
echo ($this->firstline > "") ? "<li>" . $this->firstline . "</li>" : "";
echo ($this->secondline > "") ? "<li>" . $this->secondline . "</li>" : "";
echo ($this->thirdline > "") ? "<li>" . $this->thirdline . "</li>" : "";
```

Answer (score -2):

try this :)

```
    ol, ul{list-style:none;}
```

Comment: I think you need to re-read the question. It's not the `list-style-type` that's the problem: it's the *empty list-items*.